# External Service Request Response Logging in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

Hi I am using spring integration to call 6 webservices.I have below implementation.

1.4 Rest service call(Calling rest services using Service Activator).And these service call are made parallely using task executor.

2.2 SOAP services using out bound gate way.I have Interceptor implementation for adding headers.This service calls will be made after above 4 rest call was done.And implemented FaultResolver interface to catch saop Fault.

My question is I want log all the external service request/response for both success and failure scenarios.What is the best approach to achieve this without performance hit in spring integration.

Comment: Please, revise your question. It looks like a mess and feels like unfinished.

Comment: Hi Artem I need to log all my external service calls in a file.My application will call 6 services using spring Integration and I want to log all those Request/Responses.I know we have wire-Tap interceptor but it's have some limitation also its not for production.Is there any other approach.

Comment: With "revising" the question I meant and edit to it, not comment which may confuse much more other peoples. And I am not sure what you mean that `WireTap` isn't for production. It is standard EI pattern, so it is something *must be*, if the logic requires such a behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Artem I got it now.Let me implement it.